# Time series analysis by taking mean value in R - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

Here is my data set: https://app.box.com/s/2g98iis1zpcu4kwm7ej58d8pf2h4vnwe

I want to plot a time series chart showing the mean value of various sentiments and emotions with 6 month break up.

I was following this article: https://juliasilge.com/blog/joy-to-the-world/

Got stuck here:

```
posnegtime <- kdn_tweets %>% 
        group_by(created_at = cut(created_at, breaks="2 months")) %>%
        summarise(negative = mean(negative),
                  positive = mean(positive)) %>% melt
```

Error:

```
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names
```

I'd also like to chart the sentiment over the days of the week and months of the year. Something like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the code that you tried and the code that produced those graphs.

Comment: I've updated the original question.

Comment: Your code works fine for me with the data you provided, as is.
Have you done modifications to kdn_tweets? If so, can you share a sample of your data so the error can be reproduced?

Comment: I've not done any changes to kdn_tweets. Still getting the same issue.